# Task :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED by generating of signed Bundle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to build signed bundle in Android Studio. And getting the following error.
This is a bit strange because the normal compilation of an application does not cause errors.
I tried To Invalidate caches/ restart, but it didn't work.

```
D:\...\ChatAdapter.java:101: error: cannot find symbol
           convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_msg_row, parent, false);
                                                  ^
 symbol:   variable chat_msg_row
 location: class layout
```

Here is my build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ksoft.findmystuff"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }


        buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.2'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:8.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.2'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.nightonke:boommenu:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.ramotion.foldingcell:folding-cell:1.2.3'
    implementation 'com.shuhart.stepview:stepview:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: The error is pointing to say that there is no `chat_msg_row.xml` present in the layout directory.

Comment: I know. The problem is that the chat_msg_row.xml is present in layout directory. Moreover. The error applies to almost all layouts. I only pointed one as an example

Comment: Did you found any solution? I'm facing similar issue